# Jasper Report Excel-CSV Export: Prevent executing excel formula

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-excel

I am using Jasper Report API 4.5 (ready to update if required for this solution). With Jasper Report I am exporting report to HTML, Excel, CSV and PDF. A situation I came across is that if data is having valid excel formula then on exporting data to Excel and CSV and viewing file to MS Excel, it executes excel formula. This causes a security issue as some data is having excel formula to perform some action on local computer then it may harm system.

We can not validate data at the time of insertion, doing so may fix the problem. But currently there is no data validation as such to prevent inserting excel formula. Preferred solution to me is to manage from Jasper Report.

My question is, is there any mechanism or export parameter which can prevent excel formula to be executed? Or is there any way to print data as is and ignore excel formula?

Comment: The [XLS Formula Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsformula/index.html#xlsformula) topic is describing how to care xls formulas

Comment: Have checked the link. But it do not tell anything about ignoring excel formula. I am more interested to not execute excel formula than execute it. This question is applicable to Excel Exporter and CSV Exporter, as both file formats are read from MS Excel.

Comment: What do you mean ignoring? If you don't  use `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula` property the text from textField will be just text. For example, `1+1` - it will be just text, not the sum (`2`). The quote from article I posted you above: `By default all data are exported as text only`

Comment: Property `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.formula` is not set. It is actually showing records directly from database. So there might be the case that somebody have inserted it as `=SUM(1,1)`, which when exported to CSV and opened from MS Excel then it will show result as `2` and not `=SUM(1,1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Excel export:**

We can use **Apache POI** or **SmartXLS** API to set cell type to `Text` externally in order to get same result from database.

*For Apache POI*, we can set cell format type as `"@"`, here is the link from Apache POI [javadoc](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setDataFormat-short-).

*For SmartXLS*, we can set workbook range style to set format type as `Text`, code snippet for it would be like below:

```
RangeStyle rangeStyle = workBook.getRangeStyle(1, 0, 50, 0);
rangeStyle.setCustomFormat("@");
```

**For CSV Export:**

Upgraded JasperReport 6.3. There is a feature to add enclosure to csv field. By default excel have single quote (**'**) as field enclosure, so that may execute the field as formula. To avoid that we can set enclosure field to (**`**).

```
SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration reportExportConf = new SimpleCsvExporterConfiguration();

reportExportConf.setFieldEnclosure("`");
reportExportConf.setForceFieldEnclosure(true);
```